# Registering new post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

```
function ms_register_blog_posts_custom_post() {
    $labels = array('name' => 'تدوينات','singular_name' => 'تدوينة','menu_name' => 'تدوينات');
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'show_ui' => true,'labels' => $labels,  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),'capability_type' => 'post','has_archive' => true, 'query_var' => true,);
    register_post_type( 'blog', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'ms_register_blog_posts_custom_post' );
```

I'm using this function to register a new post type, when I remove the `flush_rewrite_rules();` and head to mysite.com/blog it gives a 404 page, when I keep it it works fine. But I know you can't flush the rewrite rules each and every single page visit on your website. So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you think it might be the characters `تدوينات`? try using `my-post-type`

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/wordpress-slug-issue-with-non-latin-characters